# MinGW shows old version of file

Tags: windows, git, mingw

I'm observing a situation where Git Bash (MinGW) is showing different contents for a particular file than everything else on the system.

In the image you can see that the file `elasticsearch.yml` has the same MD5 hash in the command prompt and in Cygwin, but under MinGW the contents are different. If I copy the file using the command prompt it has the correct, original hash, but if I copy it using MinGW the new copy has the same contents as the phantom MinGW version.

What is causing this phenomenon, and how can I solve it?

I'm running Windows Server 2012, 64 bit, and MinGW from Git version `1.9.5.msysgit.1`.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check to see if you have an entry in the virtualization overlay. Look in "`%APPDATA%\Local\VirtualStore`" for this file in a matching replicated directory tree. This is where copies of files can end up if the right combination of UAC and permissions is present. It is possible on of these is not using the virtualized calls and is managing to by-pass this.

Comment: That path didn't resolve for me (also I think it's missing a `%`), but the file was indeed there under `C:\Users\<my-user-name>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`. I'm amazed. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed the variable expansion. This virtualization mechanism is an enormous pain.